# How to add a Fragment to a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've a SplashScreen, which is a ViewPager and I need to add the Login Fragment to it on tap.

This is my PagerAdapter:

```
public class SplashSAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context ssContext;
    Activity _activity;
    private int[] ssImages = new int[] { R.drawable.splashscreen1,R.drawable.splashscreen2, R.drawable.splashscreen3 };

    public SplashSAdapter(Context ssContext, Activity activity) {
        this.ssContext = ssContext;
        this._activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ssImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View ssView, Object ssObject) {
        return ssView == ((ImageView) ssObject);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup ssContainer, int ssPosition) {
        ImageView ssImageView = new ImageView(ssContext);
        ssImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        ssImageView.setImageResource(ssImages[ssPosition]);
        ((ViewPager) ssContainer).addView(ssImageView, 0);
        ssImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                onClickSplashScreen();
            }
        });

        return ssImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup ssContainer, int ssPosition,
            Object ssObject) {
        ((ViewPager) ssContainer).removeView((ImageView) ssObject);
    }

    public void onClickSplashScreen(){
}
```

So, onClickSplashScreen, how do I add a Fragment there?

Comment: ViewPager is a view that allows a user to swipe from a view to another. It lloks to me you should open a new activity for login and close this one. Or replace the fragment that owns the viewpager with the login fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should user FragmentPagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter,

Examples can be found here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score -2):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = this._activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

will this help you?